# Creating a Google Calendar remotely

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've been researching this question for the last few weeks and have had no success trying to connect to Google through OAuth1 OR 2.

I have a client that needs a separate Calendar for each of the homes they are building.  On creation of a new home in the database, I want to create a calendar and save the Id of the created calendar.

What options do I have to do this?

It seems like the only way is to have the user get redirected to Google and login to add a calendar... I want to use a static Google account and simply create the calendar that way, without having the annoying "Login to google" screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google api lets you to do whatever you need with a Calendar using their provided libraries. Let's take a look: [Google Developer: Instantiate Google Calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate)

Comment: This is finally getting me somewhere, but when I try to use the example I ran into this problem I submitted:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/issues/detail?id=149&thanks=149&ts=1340831485

Comment: Sorry @EricCarmichael I haven't worked with Google php library for a while, so I don't remember what is the meaning of that parameters :S

Answer (score 0):

This SO posts discusses that. Specifically pay attention to the line in the accepted answer where it is mentions the process for adding a new calendar is similar to adding an event.

[SO: Google Calendar API Selecting and creating Calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534373/google-calendar-api-selecting-creating-calendars)

I also came across this tutorial which may be helpful in terms of other actions on the calendar once it has been created.

[IBM Developer Works: Integrate your PHP Application with Google Calendar](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googleclndr/)